# PHP's include_path setting

Tags: php

I'm sure I'm just being a bit stupid, but the [`include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) docs seem to be a bit confusing; what is

```
Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the 
current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include
'./file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.
```

actually trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is
>
> > Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the 
> >     current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include
> >     './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.
>
> actually trying to say?

Assume you want to use `include_path` to search in folder `/somepath/foo/includes` for include files when you do not specify the path explicitly. You may have most of your include files laying there, so that should be not too inefficient.

Now you are including `baz.php`, `xzy.php` and `123.php` from that directory – and if you have given `.` first in the `include_path`, then PHP will search the current directory first always, although in most cases the file will be located in the `/somepath/foo/includes` folder.

If you *don’t* specify `.` at the beginning of your include path and use `./abc.php` explicitly when you are including a file from the current directory (special case, not one of your “normal” includes), then for *all other* of your include files that you just include using `baz.php`, `xzy.php` and `123.php`, PHP will *not* have to search the current directory first – which is useless, since those files are located in your special include folder; so PHP can go look there in the first place.

Comment: I almost posted this word for word - though I was going to note that it's still a micro-optimisation and something I'd expect to be handled automatically if you were to utilise some kind of opcode cache but I can't find any info on that part.  I don't suppose you know otherwise?

Comment: Thanks - I think this is a much better explanation than the official docs. I think I'd subconsciously either have all my 'included' files in the same folder _or_ just include 'special' ones directly anyway - so it's good to know that's what's recommended!

Comment: @Emissary: I don’t know. And I agree, it’s rather micro optimization. Specifying a large number of include paths should be avoided though I think, because looking through multiple directories until an include file is “finally” found doesn’t sound very good to me; and I think specifying the complete path each time (you should know where your include files are located, right?) is the better way to go – either using an absolute path from the server root (maybe specified using a configurable constant base path), or specifying exactly _one_ `include_path` directory as the base from where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It is talking about dot at the begining in the include_path.

Form PHP Documentation : `If filename begins with ./ or ../, it is looked only in the current working directory.`

`./ is the current directory. It is largely the same as just someFile.php.In many cases \it doesn't check any standard places PHP might look for a file, instead checking only the current directory.`

`Edited.` 'more efficient' means that it better to set path in such way with dot. In other way it will try to find not only in the current working directory. So, it can be a problem if you want to include file in the some directory, but the file is not exist, it will try to find in other path, and it can take some time and make wrong include or just an error.

Comment: I know `./` is the current directory - I just don't understand what the documentation is trying to say is more efficient